# How can I find the value of a function at some point in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

For example, if I define the following in Matlab,

```
f(x) = x^2 + 3x - 2
```

How do I find what value the function evaluates to when x = 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a file called `f.m` that contains:

```
function y = f(x)
y = x^2 + 3x - 2
```

then in the command window, type f(3) and you should get back `ans=16`

See documentation on creating functions in MATLAB: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/function.html

You can also use [polyval(p,x)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyval.html) where `p = [1 3 -2]` in your example (the coeffients of your polynomial in descending order) and you will get the value of the polynomial at that point `x` (in your case, you would pass in 3).

Comment: Not to forget `f = @(x) x.^2 + 3.*x - 2; f(3)`.